# Change filter in Silverlight Pivot Viewer to use AND instead of OR

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I need to modify the way the filter acts in the Silverlight Pivot viewer.

I have this filter:

Keywords:
x Keyword a
_ Keyword b
x Keyword c
_ Keyword d
_ Keyword e

The filter generates “Keyword a OR Keyword c”. What I need is “Keyword a AND Keyword c”.

Is that possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What Poker Villain says is quite right but that doesn't mean the `PivotViewer` is not a solution for you.  I had a similar problem with a system I've been working on and managed to find a suitable way of making the `PivotViewer` play nice.  This will only work for JIT collections though since it relies on re-fetching the data.

Essentially the system I've been working on is a case management system.  Much of the data associated with a case is mutually exclusive and so fits the model of the `PivotViewer` but there is also the ability to add 'tags' to a case and like you suggest, often the user will want to combinational logic there.  Here's what I did to fix the problem.

First off,..you're gonna want a copy of [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/).  Now in the explorer tab of SSpy, you can drill right down the Visual Tree and look at the guts of the `PivotViewer`.  Here's how mine looks...

[image]

You can see I've drilled right down into the control named 'PART_FacetPane'.  Below that there's a bunch of `CustomAccordianItem`s.  Essentially, you just need to subclass the PivotViewer (that's why mine says PivotViewerEx) and override the `OnApplyTemplate` method.

In here you will be able to use `GetTemplateChild` or some other means to navigate the VisualTree and add another control yourself.  In my project, I used a simple tag cloud control I'd previously built.

What I do is handle the events of the tag cloud control and append querystring values to the URL used to build the CXML and filter the data based on these parameters.  It's not as fluid as being able to filter the data 'live' as it were but it's a solution for now.

It's probably worth mentioning that depending on your circumstances, you may need to add a final, randomly generated querystring value to the CXML URL so you don't get a cached copy of the data.

HTH, Stimul8d.

Comment: great answer - i will take it for a spin and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

bottom line ... NO.
You get what you get with this control. (for now)

but you could generate a "dummy" facet that was the concatenation of all the keywords for an item.  But if you had more than a few keywords, it would look very ugly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Got 100+ keywords so probably not a solution.

Comment: Sorry bro. Can't be done Now. Will be possible with pivot v2 as announced in silverlight firestarter though.